# $(this).attr('id') returns undefined error jquery for .each

Tags: jquery, undefined, each, attr

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="bio" id="bio-1">Test 1</div>
<div class="bio" id="bio-2">Test 2</div>
```

and the Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var bio = $('.bio');
        bio.each(function (){
            var bioId = $(this).attr('id');
            bioId.click(function() {            
                    $(this).addClass('visible');
             });
         });
 });
```

But I'm getting an error in the console saying bioId is undefined. Any thoughts?
http://jsfiddle.net/xm679zbe/

Comment: Whatever value `bioId` has, it definitely is not a jQuery object, so you can't call `click` on it. I think you just want `$('.bio').click(function() {  $(this).addClass('visible'); });`. No need to make it more complicated than it is.

Comment: *"...I'm getting an error in the console saying bioId is undefined...."* I suspect it's telling you that `bioId.click` is undefined, rather than `bioId`. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this line:

```
var bioId = $(this).attr('id');
```

`bioId` will hold either a string or `undefined`. It will not refer to a jQuery object.

If your goal is to add a `visible` class to any `.bio` element when it's clicked, then:

```
$(".bio").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("visible");
});
```

...although (working from the name), if they aren't "visible" to start with, how could you click them?

Comment: The Fiddle contains CSS that defines the `visible` class' styling (it's just a different color, but it's an interesting choice for the name).

Comment: @AstroCB: Thanks. Pity that information wasn't in the question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to add class visible whenever you click on ".bio", so you don't have to write such a complicated code. Simply do

```
$(".bio").on("click",function(){
$(this).addClass("visible");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're calling `.click()` on the `id` attribute, not the jQuery object.

`$(this).attr('id');` will give you the element's ID in the form of a string, which you cannot add an event listener to.

Set `bioId` to the actual object in the iteration:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bio = $('.bio');
    bio.each(function () {
        var bioId = $(this);
        bioId.click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('visible');
        });
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/xm679zbe/2/)

Alternatively, you could remove the variables altogether:

```
$('.bio').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("visible");
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/xm679zbe/3/)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are iterating throught the elements which contains the class `.bio` there's no need to extract the id and set the new class, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var bio = $('.bio');
        bio.each(function (){
            $(this).click(function() {            
                    $(this).addClass('visible');
             });
         });
 });
```

Hope this works :)